# Exception when starting vaadin 14 website with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I developed a vaadin website including spring boot. The website is already running in production mode and the tomcat starts, but the following exception comes up the first time you access it via the browser:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Aug 30 11:11:55 CEST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1594)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1557)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupFrameworkLibraries(BootstrapHandler.java:893)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupDocumentHead(BootstrapHandler.java:770)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.getBootstrapPage(BootstrapHandler.java:539)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:480)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The stats file from webpack (stats.json) was not found.
The application is running in production mode.Verify that build-frontend task has executed successfully and that stats.json is on the classpath.Or switch application to development mode.
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.appendNpmBundle(BootstrapHandler.java:925)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupFrameworkLibraries(BootstrapHandler.java:891)
... 57 more

Project Info:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.8.16</vaadin.version>
      <!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar" -->
      <start-class>com.rofu.onlinestatistikcenter.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Isn't the message *The stats file from webpack (stats.json) was not found. The application is running in production mode.Verify that build-frontend task has executed successfully and that stats.json is on the classpath.Or switch application to development mode.* clear?

Comment: The jar is supposed to run on a server, so it has to run in production mode. What exactly do I need to add to the classpath?

Comment: have you build it with mvn package -Pproduction

Comment: Thank you so much, it's finally working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a maven build run configuration in Eclipse that has "package -Pproduction" as the goal.

[image]

When it runs it creates a jar file in the target directory that works.

Thanks to @Simon Martinelli